# What is the difference between C and embedded C?

Tags: c, embedded

Can any body tell me the differences between them?

Comment: Are you referring to C++ and Embedded C++?

Comment: Which compilers implement Embedded C?

Comment: @mdec I imagine he's talking about C, but most people here would also like to know the differences for cpp as well, me being one. Apart from not knowing at all the difference between embedded or not (apart from basically its SoC), it would also be interesting to compare the differences of c/embededd c and differences of cpp/embedded cpp.

Answer (score 40):

In the C standard, a standalone implementation doesn't have to provide all of the library functions that a hosted implementation has to provide.  The C standard doesn't care about embedded, but vendors of embedded systems usually provide standalone implementations with whatever amount of libraries they're willing to provide.

C is a widely used general purpose high level programming language mainly intended for system programming.

Embedded C is an extension to C programming language that provides support for developing efficient programs for embedded devices.It is not a part of the C language

You can also refer to the articles below:

- [Difference  between C and Embedded C](http://www.differencebetween.info/difference-between-c-and-embedded-c)
- [Embedded C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedded_C)
- [ISO/IEC J TC1 SC22 WG14 N1169](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1169.pdf)

Comment: ISO/IEC J TC1 SC22 WG14 N1169 link seems to be dead

Answer (score 15):

**Embedded C is generally an extension of the C language**, they are more or less similar. However, *some differences do exist*, such as:

- C is generally used for desktop computers, while embedded C is for microcontroller based applications.
- C can use the resources of a desktop PC like memory, OS, etc. While, embedded C has to use with the limited resources, such as RAM, ROM, I/Os on an embedded processor.
- Embedded C includes extra features over C, such as fixed point types, multiple memory areas, and I/O register mapping.
- Compilers for C (ANSI C) typically generate OS dependant executables. Embedded C requires compilers to create files to be downloaded to the microcontrollers/microprocessors where it needs to run.

Refer [difference between C and embedded C](http://www.differencebetween.info/difference-between-c-and-embedded-c)

Answer (score 8):

Basically, there isn't one.  Embedded refers to the hosting computer / microcontroller, not the language.  The embeddded system might have fewer resources and interfaces for the programmer to play with, and hence C will be used differently, but it is still the same ISO defined language.

Comment: Embedded C is a standardised extension of the C language with features which are commonly used in embedded systems but not elsewhere such as fixed point arithmetic.

Answer (score 5):

1: C is a type of computer programming language.
   While embedded C is a set of language extensions for the C Programming language.

2: C has a free-format program source code, in a desktop computer.
   while embedded C has different format based on embedded processor (micro- 
   controllers/microprocessors).

3: C have normal optimization, in programming.
   while embedded C high level optimization in programming.

4: C programming must have required operating system.
   while embedded C may or may not be required operating system.

5: C can use resources from OS, memory, etc, i.e all resources from desktop computer can 
   be used by C.
    while embedded C can use limited resources, like RAM, ROM, and I/Os on an embedded 
    processor.

Answer (score 1):

Embedded environment, sometime, there is no MMU, less memory, less storage space.
In C programming level, almost same, cross compiler do their job.

Answer (score 1):

c cant access physical address, embedded c can access physical address
embedded c variable address is stored in stack,
in embedded c variable should be declaired at the begining of the block
embedded c input output port are used but in c printf and scanf used

Comment: _in embedded c variable should be declaired at the begining of the block_ No. No reason to do so if you have a compiler that supports C99, C11 or C18. Only C89/C90 compiler don't support that, regardless if the are on freestanding or hosted environment.

Answer (score -6):

C is a only programming language its used in system programming.
but embedded C is used to implement the projects like real time applications

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your answer does not add value compared to the answers already given. When you have enough reputation points you will be able to add comments, but for now please do not post comments as answers.

Comment: Very much incorrect.